# Cordova/Phonegap Geolocation

Tags: cordova, gps, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I'm writing a Cordova/Phonegap app and I want to use Geolocation plugin to obtain longitude and latitude. This is my code:

```
$scope.showCoord = function() {
        var onSuccess = function(position) {
            console.log("Latitude: "+position.coords.latitude);
            console.log("Longitude: "+position.coords.longitude);
        };

        function onError(error) {
            console.log("Code: "+error.code);
            console.log("Message: "+error.message);
        };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
    }
```

When I try this plugin with the GPS it works very well but when I try it without GPS I receive timeout...I change the timeout to 100000 but doesn't work. Furthermore in my config.xml I added this code:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Based on your comment below I've rewritten my answer

When you set `enableHighAccuracy: true`, the app is saying to the OS "give me a high accuracy position from the GPS hardware". If GPS is enabled in the OS settings, the GPS hardware is available, so requesting a high accuracy position will cause the OS to engage the GPS hardware to retrieve a high accuracy position. However, if GPS is disabled in the OS settings, then the high accuracy position that your app requested cannot be supplied by the OS, hence the error callback.

If you set `enableHighAccuracy: false`, the app is saying to the OS "give me a location of any accuracy", so the OS will return a location using cell triangulation/Wifi (or GPS if it is currently activated by another app).

So to cater for both high and low accuracy positions, you could first try for a high accuracy one, and if that fails, then request a low accuracy one. For example:

```
var maxAge = 3000, timeout = 5000;

var onSuccess = function(position) {
    console.log("Latitude: "+position.coords.latitude);
    console.log("Longitude: "+position.coords.longitude);
};

function onError(error) {
    console.log("Code: "+error.code);
    console.log("Message: "+error.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, function(error) {
    console.log("Failed to retrieve high accuracy position - trying to retrieve low accuracy");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: maxAge, timeout: timeout, enableHighAccuracy: false });
}, { maximumAge: maxAge, timeout: timeout, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

Comment: Sorry I want to obtain the GPS when it is active and when it is off I want to receive the coord from network

Comment: It doesn't work for me...If I set the timeout to 1 min, I obtain always timeout...I'm testing on my android device

Comment: Furthermore if I turn off the connection I receive timeout when I must receive POSITION_UNAVAILABLE

Comment: How are you testing the scenario without GPS? In Android 4, Location mode High Accuracy will GPS+Wifi+Cell location; Battery saving will using Wifi+Cell location

Comment: I istalled my app on my devide and I ispected it on my browser so I can turn off or turn on my gps, my wifi but doesn't work

Comment: You need to make sure you are only disabling GPS and not Location Services, otherwise the app will not receive any location data - it sounds like this is what's happening in your case due to the errors you are getting Do this by setting the Location mode to "Battery saving" in Android settings